# Why is the JAC VOR an Initial Approach Fix for the KJAC VORDME Rwy 19 Approach?

Tags: approach

See the attached KJAC VOR/DME Rwy 19 approach.

QUESTION: Why is the JAC VOR an IAF for this approach?

There isn't a procedure turn to use this VOR as a functional IAF, 
and the twin peaks (13,770' & 12,695' plus 7,139') should be enough to disuade you from trying while IMC.

The FAA Instrument flying handbook defines an IAF as:

Initial approach fix (IAF). The fix depicted on IAP charts
where the instrument approach procedure (IAP) begins unless
otherwise authorized by ATC.

The chart doesn't indicate radar contact required. I don't see any other route from the VOR JAC IAF to establish one's self on the final approach.
Hence the question on why the reason for labeling the JAC VOR as an IAF for this approach?

[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer but JAC isn't marked as an IAF on the FAA plate. Perhaps a charting error by Jeppesen?

Comment: @Pondlife beat me to it but that is my conclusion as well.

Comment: @Greg I tried to transform the title in a question (we're on a Q&A website) but I'm not quite sure it completely reflects what you're asking. feel free to edit it again.

Comment: Thanks I edited the title. Why is the JAC VOR and Initial Approach Fix for the KJAC VOR/DME Rwy 19 approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an IAF according to the FAA approach plate:

[image: KJAC VOR/DME RWY 19]

Besides not being identified as an IAF, JAC could only be an IAF if there was a charted course reversal.  As the FAA approach plate specifically says "Procedure Turn NA" that possibility is ruled out.